# Redis caching with ServiceStack OrmLite and SQL Server persistence

Tags: redis, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have a Web app (ASP.NET/C#) with SQL Server backend. We use ServiceStack OrmLite as our POCO Micro ORM. We would now like to extend a part of our app to cache frequently-read data (mainly a collection of POCO objects as values, with numeric keys). But I'm not sure how to go about integrating a simple caching solution (in-memory or Redis based) that works seamlessly with OrmLite and MSSQL as the Master database.

I've read about the ServiceStack Redis Client, MemoryCacheClient and Multi nested database connections (OrmLiteConnectionFactory), but I couldn't find any examples, tutorial or code samples to learn more about implementing caching that works with OrmLite.

Any suggestions or links will be helpful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to implement the caching logic yourself, but it's not much work - here's a pseudocode example:

```
    public class QueryObject
    {
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooResponse
    {
        public List<Dto> Data { get; set; }
    }


    public FooResponse GetFooData(QueryObject queryObject)
    {
        using (var dbConn = connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        using (var cache = redisClientsManager.GetCacheClient())
        {
            var cacheKey = string.Format("fooQuery:{0}", queryObject.GetHashCode()); //insert your own logic for generating a cache key here
            var response = cache.Get<Response>(cacheKey);

            //return cached result
            if (response != null) return response;

            //not cached - hit the DB and cache the result
            response = new FooResponse()
                {
                    Data =
                        dbConn.Select<Foo>(
                            x => x.DateTime > queryObject.StartDate.Value && x.Name.StartsWith(queryObject.SomeString)).ToList()
                };
            cache.Add(cacheKey, response, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15)); //the next time we get the same query in the next 15 mins will return cached result
            return response;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, that would work. I was hoping that there might be a better (more seamless, less gluing involved) way to make OrmLite and Redis Client work together. It's a feature worth integrating in OrmLite I suppose.

Comment: If you are looking for an Orm with plugin extensibility then you probably need NHibernate - indeed, someone has plugged in ServiceStack.Redis caching already, see here: http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/05/17/NHibernate-Caching-with-Redis.aspx

OrmLite is focussed on being lightweight and blazing fast at the expense of features, NHibernate is an 800lb gorilla which isn't suited to all projects but if you need features such as plug-in caching, audit logging, full-text indexing with Lucene and more, then it's definitely worth looking at but comes at with the expense of complexity and performance.

Comment: Agreed Dan. NHibernate is too bloated (and will be slow) for my needs. I guess I can just use something along the lines of the wrapper code you've provided.

Answer (score 4):

I use this extension to help simplify the integration between the db and the cache.

```
public static class ICacheClientExtensions
{
    public static T ToResultUsingCache<T>(this ICacheClient cache, string cacheKey, Func<T> fn, int hours = 1) where T : class
    {
        var cacheResult = cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
        if (cacheResult != null)
        {
            return cacheResult;
        }
        var result = fn();
        if (result == null) return null;
        cache.Set(cacheKey, result, TimeSpan.FromHours(hours));
        return result;
    } 
}

public class MyService : Service
{
    public Data Get(GetData request)
    {
        var key = UrnId.Create<Data>(request.Id);

        Func<Data> fn = () => Db.GetData(request.Id);

        return Cache.ToResultUsingCache(key, fn);
    }

    [Route("/data/{id}")]
    public class GetData: IReturn<Data>
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [Service stack caching wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). It gives detailed info about caching. Now in your case from the details you are providing I can say that you can go for any kind of caching. As of now it will not make any difference.

PS: A piece of advice caching should be done when there is no option or the only thing pending in application. Because it comes with it's own problem is invalidating caching, managing and all that. So, if you application is not too big, just leave it for now.